# Using youtube-dl to download Deezer playlist?

Tags: youtube-dl

Is it possible to download a Deezer.com playlist using youtube-dl? I tried inputting the Deezer playlist link and it only downloads 30 second samples of the songs. Any way to get the full songs?

Answer (score 2):

While `youtube-dl` have [supported](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html) DeezerPlaylist, but unfortunately if you try download playlist from Deezer, it will only download preview version of 30 seconds of each file.

On their [GitHub](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) page, you can clearly saw several user desperately trying to get Deezer Playlist/Track working fully downloadable with `youtube-dl`. Some has opened new issues about it:

- https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/10049
- https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/11411

Nevertheless, an contributor has create a python script named [`deezer.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/deezer.py), you can consider try this script for downloading purpose. I don't know what the script does as there aren't description yet, moreover I'm not familiar with python.

#### Update

Sadly, even [`deezer.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/deezer.py) script unable to grab full length of track, someone has [confirmed](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/11833#event-936337375) this:

> Currently only 30 seconds previews are supported.
>
> Duplicate of #10049.

So most likely you have to be patient, until `youtube-dl` developer support full track.

Comment: yes the Deezer.py script is the one I'm trying to figure out how to use :/ apparently it works for downloading playlists but I don't know Python at all so I don't even know where to start to use it for downloading playlists. I haven't found any info anywhere with help

Answer (score -1):

I posted a pull request for youtube-dl: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/pull/13194, which adds full deezer support. It is based on an earlier  version available, via tor, on http://haklab4ulibiyeix.onion/revres/DeezerDownloader/.

There is a separate script, which extract's mp3's from your browser's .har file ( saved from ctrl-shift-i - network debugger ).
This works best from firefox, where the .har response size limit is user configurable.

http://haklab4ulibiyeix.onion/revres/DeezerDownloader/blob/master/decodehar.py

Comment: how would one exactly use your DeezerDownloader python script? I downloaded the deezer-download.py and navigated cmd to the scripts folder then ran "python" through cmd and then executed "deezer-downloader.py https://www.deezer.com/track/109176408" and got this error :

>>> deezer-downloader.py https://www.deezer.com/track/109176408
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    deezer-downloader.py https://www.deezer.com/track/109176408
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You run python scripts from the commandline as `python3 deezer-downloader.py  http://deezer.com/artist/12312121`.